# How can I grab the API parameter in a Django viewset?

Tags: python, django, rest

I am building a Django application that exposes a REST API by which users can query my application's models. I'm following the instructions [**here**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart#testing-our-api)

My Route looks like this in mySites url.py:

```
router.register(r'myObjects', views.MyObjectsViewSet)
....
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

My Serializer looks like this:

```
class MyObjectSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyObject
    fields = ('id', 'name',)
```

My Viewset looks like this:

```
class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyObjects.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyObjectSerializer
```

When I hit the API /api/myObjects/ it gives me a listing of all the myObject models.
When I hit the API /api/myObjects/60/ it gives me only the myObject with id == 60. 
Great so far!

However, I want to change the logic of MyObjectsViewSet() such that I can manipulate/change what it returns when I hit /api/myObjects/60/. So instead of doing **MyObjects.objects.all()** I want to do something more complex based on the myObject ID of 60. But how can I do that?? In this viewset, how can I grab that number 60? It is not passed in as an argument. But I really need it!

Answer (score 22):

In your router, register one more url with:

```
router.register(r'myObjects/(?P<id>\d+)', views.MyObjectsViewSet)
```

and in your viewset you can grab the id with:

```
self.kwargs['id']
```

Ref: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#filtering-against-the-url

Comment: This looks very promising! Exactly what I need.
However, when I print self.kwargs['id'] in the viewset, I get the following error: name 'self' is not defined

Comment: You will have to do your complex operation in a viewset method. Documentation shows an example with get_queryset

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering#filtering-against-the-url

Comment: Why was this voted so high? This creates more than 1 new url by the nature of it being a viewset...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can update your view for multiple operations such as

```
class RetrieveUpdateAPIView(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                        mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                        generics.SingleObjectAPIView):
"""
Concrete view for retrieving or updating a model instance.
FIXME: the newest version of rest_framework has this class
"""

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Please watch this [tutorial](https://godjango.com/41-start-your-api-django-rest-framework-part-1/) it will help you to understand the REST framework.

Answer (score 0):

I feel [cyriacthomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463512/cyriacthomas) is right but might need a bit more details. Although I am just unsure as to why the `self` is used.

I believe the snippet would look like:

```
class MyObjectsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyObjects.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyObjectSerializer

    # Inside your class, you overwrite the retrieve function
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj_id = kwargs['id']

        query = MyObjects.objects.get(obj_id)

        # do something with data

        return self.serializer_class(data=query).data
```